# Row and Column numbers of selected cells

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtableview, qtablewidget

### Background:

I have a simple `QTableWidget` with multiple rows and columns. Users can select multiple rows of cell withtin the same column at each time. (They can only select cells within the same column at one time)

Something like this:

[image]

### Objective:

I want to detect the,

1. Starting row number
2. Ending row number, and
3. Column number of the selection made upon `mouse release`.

### My Attempt:

I think my problem has 2 parts,

- First is to detect the `mouse release` event. But after looking through the documentation, I could not find the `mouse release event`. All I can see is `Cellclicked`, `Cellchanged`, etc. So, How do I detect the mouse release event in `QTableWidget`?
- Second is to get the `Row` and `Column` number of selections.I found that there is this function called `selectedIndexes()` which helps me get the indexes. Something like this:

  ```
  for item in self.calendar.selectedIndexes():
      print item.row(),item.column()
  ```

But I am not sure if this is the right way to do it. All I want is to check at which row does the selection starts and ends, plus the column that the selection is being made. Any good way to do it?

Comment: Does the selection order matters? I mean is the result the same if you select the cells from the top to the bottom and if you select from bottom to the top?

Comment: @DrHaze It should not matter.Actually,all I need is the `min` and `max` row indexes, plus the `column` index.

Comment: Sorry, got some work to do, I'm cleaning the code and filling the table and I post my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind this code is to create a custom QTableWidget class that is adding a mouse release event.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class CustomQTableWidget(QtGui.QTableWidget):    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QTableWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        #Fill Qtable
        self.insertColumn (0)
        self.insertColumn (1)
        self.insertColumn (2)
        self.insertColumn (3)
        self.insertRow (0)
        self.insertRow (1)
        self.insertRow (2)
        self.insertRow (3)
        self.insertRow (4)
        self.insertRow (5)
        self.insertRow (6)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton: #Release event only if done with left button, you can remove if necessary

            #Your code should go here
            indexSelection = []

            for item in self.selectedIndexes(): 
                indexSelection.append( str(item.row())+ "-" + str(item.column()) )

            print indexSelection


class MyDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.tableWidget = CustomQTableWidget() #Create a custom QtableWidget
        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout() #Put stuff in a layout...
        hbox.addWidget(self.tableWidget) #...
        self.setLayout(hbox) #...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyDialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This output should look like this when releasing the left button:

```
>>> ['1-1', '2-1', '3-1', '4-1', '5-1']
```

I guess you will be able to use the returned data according to your needs.

Comment: thanks a lot!, looking fine but when i make a second selection, the first selection of items do no disappear. I thought normally, as soon as you click on a cell, the previous selection of cells should be auto deselect. Any idea what is causing this behavior?

Comment: You need to reimplement an other event in order to call QTableWidget::clearSelection(). Try adding self.clearSelection() at the beginning of mouseReleasedEvent(), but I guess this is not the behaviour you desire. I have to go and unfortunately I won't be able to do further coding until the end of the week-end. I'll be back to you then.

Comment: @ChrisAung. When reimplementing event handlers you need to call the base-class method if you want to keep the existing behaviour. So add `super(CustomQTableWidget, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)` to the end of `mouseReleaseEvent` to restore the normal selection behaviour.